# Nginx Passenger MySQL connects only locally

Tags: nginx, mysql, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

Fresh server, installed using the [digital ocean guide here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Passenger 5.0.18
- Nginx 1.8.0

I can deploy my app to the server via capistrano no problem. I can also load the rails console using `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails c` and query `User.first` with proper returns.

Nginx doesn't seem to want to connect to the proper database.

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
```

It keeps trying to connect to `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` which is a local IP instead of `YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY` which is a remote RDS server as defined in the `database.yml`.

The error page shows `RAILS_ENV` is set to `production`.

Comment: Nginx doesn't connect to mysql. It is passenger failing. Seems that Rails is taking the configuraton from some other file

Comment: @ignivs Right, bad wording. How do I determine exactly what Passenger is loading for its database.yml, it appears that's what's wrong. The app_root is correct.

Comment: Took a look on the problem, do you happen to have a config.ru file in your rails application?
if so, you may have to define ` RACK_ENV=production `

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the environmental variables were not being loaded into Nginx properly.

`/etc/environments` is where the variables were stored and the call to load them needed to be placed higher up in the .bashrc